# How Can I Update My Datagridview Realtime With Two Or More User?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the same app. Installed in pc 1 and pc 2 the connection string is pointing to my database server using IP address, for example if user 1 accessing table_employee and user 2 accessing table_employee also, how can I update my datagridview realtime in the app. If user 1 making a changes in the same table and user 2 will know and his/her datagridview will update also?

I have use timer for every 3-5 secs datagridview will refresh with or without changes, using timer will make your app. Lag if there are thousands of data stored in database and datagridview will load/refresh that info. Every 3-5 secs in the future, and I need another solution/way/opinion to do this?

Thank you!
vb.net 2010, Microsoft Sql Server 2014

Comment: Your question is too broad for a specific answer but I will provide some pointers. Firstly, don't reload all the data every time. If you store the time of the last change in each record then you can easily retrieve only those records that have changed since the last query. Secondly, if you want to avoid polling altogether, look into the `SqlDependency` class.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally one cannot update a datagridview real time in Access.  It is an 'event driven' application rather than an executable - intending to have a user/driver trigger events.

You know about the form timer event - and that is the normal work-around to this situation.

The fact that the sheet takes a long time to re-query is somewhat of a different issue.  That may possibly be improved depending on the cause.  Linked excel sheets are slower than linked Access tables, and other causes involving a query record set such as sorting and look ups might be able to be addressed in other ways so that the refresh is less noticeable.